# delwin(),endwin(), not working inside a condiional statement

Tags: c, ncurses

As per logic, the below code must end the window and must return the console window with output of ls but its returning the window with a black background and in that window every command is running but it is not displayed that what i am writing and output is coming in a pretty unusual manner even though i had not used noecho().

```
else if(selected_item==0){
  wprintw(messagebar,"You have selected menu SHAILENDRA SINGH.",1);
  write_data0();
  if(fork())
    wait(0);
  else
    execlp("clear","clear",(char *)NULL);
  execlp("ls","ls",(char *)NULL);
  execlp("konsole","konsole",(char *)NULL);
  ESCAPE;
  refresh();
  delwin(menubar);
  delwin(messagebar);

  endwin();
}
```

need help and suggestion in removing this bug in my code.

Comment: No comments and too little code (what the hell is `write_data0` and `ESCAPE`). We don't really read minds, you know. :)

Comment: write_data0 is a function and escape is defined in the starting as 27.And one thing "SIR",i am SORRY that i didnt explain each term over in the code.

Answer (score 3):

`execlp` will end the current program and run the called program instead.

Anything after `execlp("ls","ls",(char *)NULL);` will never get executed.

**You need a `fork` for each `execlp`.**

Comment: so what can be done in order to end my main program or open the called program in another terminal and end this terminal.

Comment: You cannot have several consequtivecalls to `execlp`. If you want to do several things in the new program you need to call a program that does all those things. My advice is that you write a shell script that does all those things and then call the shell script using `execlp`.

Comment: +1, but some quibbling. You _can_ have consecutive calls to `execlp()`, but the second will only be executed if the first fails. In the example, it is improbable that a path-based search for `ls` will fail, so the second is unlikely to be executed. In other cases, you might have `execlp("obscure-but-convenient", ...);` followed by `execlp("common-but-inconvenient", ...)` to try doing a job two different ways, but that would be commented to explain what's going on. Your analysis applies fully to the code in the question. (Curses can clear the screen; there's no need to execute the program).

Comment: LMGTFY: http://linux.die.net/man/3/curs_clear  erase, werase, clear, wclear, clrtobot, wclrtobot, clrtoeol, wclrtoeol - clear all or part of a curses window

Comment: its done,i just gave a goto out; keyword and in the last defined that out with delwin() and endwin().For checking whether any code after execlp() was runing or not, write a code to print something in a file and it was working